# How to configure Apache Kafka to sending data at specified time?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets consider the following abstaract schema of working Apache Kafka:

```
Poducers ->(Send messages) -> Apache Kafka -> (Resend to customers) -> Customers
```

It is possible to configure Kafka to send messages to customers at the specified time?

The second question is it real to roll back message to Kafka from customer?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " roll back message to Kafka" ? Do you mean read an earlier message? Or put a message back onto Kafka from the consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get the question, you want to send data to a customer at a particular point in time. If using [Lenses](http://landoop.com) for Apache Kafka it could be as simple as

`#cron the following to execute daily at 24:00
curl -XGET http://lenses-host:port/api/sql/data?sql=SELECT * from topicA WHERE customer = 'customerA WHERE _ts > 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'' > customerA.json
send info@customerA.com customerA.json`

So to answer first part of the question, you need to build your consumer logic. Rollback is not supported in Kafka, although you could easily do something like:

`INSERT INTO topicB SELECT * from topicA WHERE _ts < '2017-12-10 00:00:00'`

So you can easily create a new topic from another one, but there are no rollback semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Consumers pull messages from Kafka; Kafka does not push ("send") them. So it's up to your consumers to pull the data when they want it.

Comment: So, then how to pull data every time(every milliseconds) and roll back message to Kafka? Can customer pull out data by conditional?

Answer (score 1):

As others have already replied, Kafka doesn't push messages to consumers but consumers pull messages from Kafka; it means that you need to write your consumer in order to pull messages from Kafka topic at specific times (or intervals).
About rollback what do you mean ? Maybe that consumer gets messages from Kafka but then it wants to re-read same messages later because errors happen during the first processing ? If yes, there are two aspects to consider about Kafka :

- Kafka has a retention of the messages that can be configured (even for days), it means that when the consumer gets messages they are not deleted from the topic partition
- instead when the consumer gets messages, it has to commit the offset so that it can trace what's the latest message read from the topic partition. This commit can be done automatically or manually so that you can commit the offset only if your process went well. In any case, you are able to re-wind the stream and decide to re-start reading the topic partition from a specific offset.

Comment: Actually you are right about here `; it means that you need to write your consumer in order to pull messages `. It was a origionly issue, that led me to Kafka. Can you another mechanism for publisher?

Answer (score 0):

Extending to Robin,

Kafka won't push messages to consumer, consumer need to pull messages from Kafka.

Look at below python snippet to read messages from Kafka:

```
running = True
while running:
    msg = c.poll(timeout=1.0)
    if not msg.error():
        print('Received message: %s' % msg.value().decode('utf-8'))
    elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
        print(msg.error())
        running = False
```

In above snippet `msg = c.poll(timeout=1.0)` is used to pull message from Kafka every second. if you want to you increase timeout to any number of seconds. these means Kafka consumer consumer will pull message from every time interval.

if you want to do schedule, you have to call poll method at schedule timings.

**Note : you session.timeout.ms should be greater than poll time**

Comment: I dont ask how to read messages in the customer side. I asked another, please read question again

Comment: You answered  partially, did not tell nothing about roll back if it is possible in Kafka.

Comment: roll back means ?? what do you mean by exactly ? can u give some example ? costumers means not consumers ?